# WiX harvest directories with heat

Tags: wix, wix3.8

I have a large project with numerous sub-directories I need to harvest files from.  I have this entry in my product.wxs file:

```
<Feature Id="DefaultFeature" Title="Main Feature" Level="1">
   <ComponentGroupRef Id="APP_DATA" />
</Feature>
```

At build time I run a bat file with a number of heat commands to harvest this directory, among others :

> "%WIX%\bin\heat" dir ".\image\App_Data" -cg APP_DATA -gg -scom -dr
>   App_Data -gl -sfrag -srd -out ".\App_Data.wxs"

This generates a file App_Data.wxs in the same folder as the Product.wxs file.  But when the build runs I get the following error :

> Product.wxs(97): error LGHT0094: Unresolved reference to symbol
>   'WixComponentGroup:APP_DATA' in section
>   'Product:{FAD0EA15-49BC-4EF8-A440-87070E4FAC7A}'

I appears that the WiX project cannot find the "APP_DATA" component group in the file App_Data.wxs.  How do I get it to do that?  I would assume there is an entry in the ProjectName.wixproj file but I have not found what you do.

I have been searching the internet and found a thousand ways to set this up but none go into enough detail about how you get the WiX project to see files generated by heat during the build.  I saw [this post](http://geoffwebbercross.blogspot.com/2013/06/using-wix-heat-to-harvest-files-for-wix.html).

Which talks about editing the `Target Name="BeforeBuild"` section of the wixproj file.  Is that the only way to get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add App_Data.wxs to your wixproj just like you'd add a code-generated cs file to a csproj.
For example, if the App_Data.wxs is in the same folder as your wixproj, you'd add the following Compile element to your ItemGroup element in the wixproj.
ProTip: If you are using a SCM that defaults to read-only you'll need to check it out every time or set to always writable.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="App_Data.wxs" />
</ItemGroup>
```